# Adding cross reference GlobalID as a report parameter

Tags: acumatica

I know how it works when we add a Cross Reference for Barcode, GlobalID, etc. under the Cross Reference tab in StockItem screen and it pulls out the inventory in Document Details tab by directly entering these numbers in InventoryID field.

However, that does not work when we enter these cross reference number in any of the report parameter where if we have InventoryID.

There could be two options here-

1. If we can add GlobalID cross reference as one of the column and make
   it searchable in InventoryId lookup in Report parameter, OR
2. If we can add a new optional report parameter of GlobalID with lookup of
   cross reference from all Stock Items.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The relationship is 1 to X so it wouldn't be trivial. A custom attribute could do it. I would suggest doing a custom report launcher, that'd be easier.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour, Custom Report Launcher? Can you please provide an example or direct me to any link for more info?

Comment: The report launcher page is not customizable so it can be easier to launch the report manually: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/04/open-a-report-in-acumatica.html

Comment: Your two approaches are not bad, it would be possible too but likely more work.

Comment: I am not sure of the two approach either. Not sure how to do that but that is what I could think of. However, you are saying to create new page/screen with those parameters and launch the report?

Comment: Because you can't customize the report launcher screen (you can't extend the graph and so on) it's often easier to launch the report manually. I'm not saying to create a new page, just launch manually. You can gather the parameter with any other mechanism and then pass the equivalent param to the report.

Comment: There's quite a few reports that work, from action menu and have some custom SmartPanel to deal with more advanced parameters.